# Android studio if/Else statement is not working right

Tags: java, android

i dont know why but my if/else statement here is not working right. it is working opposite the given condition.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int rand1;
private int rand2;
private int points;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    points=0;
    pickRandomNumbers();
}

private void pickRandomNumbers()
{
    Random randy = new Random();
    int rand1 = randy.nextInt(10);
    int rand2 = randy.nextInt(10);
    Button lbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button);
    lbutt.setText(Integer.toString(rand1));
    Button rbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button);
    rbutt.setText(Integer.toString(rand2));
}

public void leftButtonClick(View view) {
    if (rand1 >= rand2){
        points++;

    } else {
        points--;

    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points_fields);
    tv.setText("Points: " + points);
    pickRandomNumbers();
}

public void rightButtonClick(View view) {
    if (rand2 >= rand1){
        points++;

    } else {
        points--;

    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points_fields);
    tv.setText("Points: " + points);
    pickRandomNumbers();
}
}
```

it should add points when rand1 is greater then rand2 and decrease points when it is smaller but it just keep adding the points.

When I changes `rand1>=rand2` to `rand1>rand2` it only decrease the points. The same is happening for both of button functions. Kindly help me understand this.

Comment: Both variables are `0` because they are defined at the class level, but never written to. You probably want to change `int rand1 = randy.nextInt(10);` to `rand1 = randy.nextInt(10);`

Comment: @Kon oh it worked thanks. I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare two global variables `rand1` and `rand2` at the top of your class. Later on, you again declare two variables with the same names. Java accepts this as valid code, because the first two can be referenced as `this.rand1` and `this.rand2`. You create the variables twice, when you really only want to create them once.

If you remove the `int` before the second declarations, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to object variables use 'this' keyword insead of creating new variable 
Here you go:

```
private void pickRandomNumbers(){
        Random randy = new Random();
        this.rand1 = randy.nextInt(10);
        this.rand2 = randy.nextInt(10);
        Button lbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button);
        lbutt.setText(Integer.toString(rand1));
        Button rbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button);
        rbutt.setText(Integer.toString(rand2));
    }
```

Comment: No, that is not required.

Comment: He created new variable instead of using one from class. So this will show him what he did wrong

Answer (score 0):

You declare new `rand1` and `rand2` variables within the scope of the `pickRandomNumbers` method. What you need to be doing is modifying the rand variables that already exist.

Try saying `this.rand1 = randy.nextInt(10)`, if you want rand1 and rand2 to work properly. That way, you are not defining a new variable within the scope of your method, but rather defining the global variables you have already declared.

Once you do this, your `leftButtonClick` method should work properly.